# Exposing ADCS OCSP on the Public Internet

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation, windows-server, ocsp

I am building a Certificate Authority using Windows Server ADCS as a 'Standalone' CA but my application would be greatly improved if I can utilise OCSP.

Is the ADCS Online Responder Role Service appropriate to be exposed on the public internet?
Are there any best-practices to harden it, and reduce it's attacker surface, for this use-case?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the ADCS Online Responder Role Service appropriate to be exposed on the public internet?

yes.

> Are there any best-practices to harden it, and reduce it's attacker surface, for this use-case?

expose only particular web site that contains OCSP application.